# Error: [ng:areq] Argument '' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: controller

I have created controller and added in routing.

Getting an error as

[ng:areq] Argument '' is not a function, got undefined

Here is the code :

controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.signup')
        .controller('signupController', signupController);
    function signupController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = "signup";
        console.log("signup controller");
    }
})();
```

Module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.signup',[]);
})();
```

Route:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.signup', ['ui.router']).config(appConfig);
    appConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    function appConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true
        });
        $stateProvider
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/signup/signup.html',
                controller: 'signupController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            });
    }

})();
```

app.module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', ['app.signup']);
})();
```

In html I binded as

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

I don't know where I am doing mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue :

Module:

```
angular.module('app.signup',[]);
```

Route:

```
angular.module('app.signup', ['ui.router']).config(appConfig);
```

Fixed issue by changing

Module:

```
angular.module('app.signup',['ui.router']);
```

Route:

```
angular.module('app.signup').config(appConfig);
```